# Why WPF XAML Intellisense shows only fields with public getters?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, intellisense

I am wondering why my Visual Studio 2017 Intellisense shows only fields with public getter. In this particular case static fields with public getter as I am trying to load into WPF content some static/constant fields.

[image: Intellisense in XAML]

As you can see in the code below I have added three various fields to `App` class, but only one (`StaticGetterName`) is shown. Funny fact is that those two other fields (`StaticField` & `ConstantName`) are working smoothly if I type it without any mistake in the spelling. The project builds and runs successfully with any of those three fields from `App` class.

I already tried with other namespaces, other classes, tried to add `static` keyword to class declaration - no change so far. Also `partial` keyword is not the issue.

This would be fine if I was about to write some binders. Showing only suggestions with public getter would make perfect sense then. But when it comes to all kind of static fields? Not too much.

I've seen other questions so I deduced that there are still some bugs around XAML Intellisense, but to clarify - this is not the scenario where Intellisense is not working. Indeed it is working, it just seems to me that it doesn't show all possible autocompletions.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace DSIK.ClientApp
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public const string ConstantName = "Client";

        public static string StaticField = ConstantName;

        public static string StaticGetterName => ConstantName;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DSIK.ClientApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DSIK.ClientApp"
        Title="{x:Static local:App.StaticGetterName}" Height="460" Width="570">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm short, because the Xaml type system and schema model only has a concept of properties.  There is no concept of fields.  The default schema context could have been made to treat CLR fields as Xaml properties, but that was never done.  I imagine there was no reason to, as public, non-final fields are generally discouraged in .NET.

The Xaml type model also has no concept of protection levels.  That was likely a deliberate design decision.  All members that can be declared in Xaml markup must be public.  It makes sense, as Xaml (or Baml) gets parsed at runtime, and Xaml can exist entirely outside the realm of projects and assemblies, so there's no clear and consistent way to deal with `internal` members, for example.  And construction of objects from Xaml doesn't occur in the context of an instance of the constructed object.  Put another way, Xaml builds objects from the *outside*, so it can't support `private` or `protected` members either.

Lastly, constants and fields are a bit different.  Even if public fields did get mapped to Xaml properties, there would be no reason to map constants, as they cannot possibly be set in Xaml.  The same would apply for read-only fields, just as it does for read-only properties (or properties without public setters).